# Alternative for teradata functions in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

Is there any alternative functions in snowflake for below teradata functions ?

```
DAYNUMBER_OF_CALENDAR(),
DayOccurrence_Of_Month(),
WeekNumber_Of_Calendar(),
MonthNumber_Of_Quarter(),
QuarterNumber_Of_Year(),
```

Comment: Proposed answers so far are not correct. The "...Number_of_Calendar" functions in Teradata are sequence values over the business calendar range, e.g.  for '2023-01-18' DayNumber_of_Calendar returns 44943 and WeekNumber_of_Calendar returns 6420 while DayOccurrence_Of_Month returns 3 (third Wednesday of the month).

Comment: can you pls give some example. what they should show for a certain date

Answer (score 1):

Can you pls try these functions ?

```
Treadata func -           snowflake func 
DAYNUMBER_OF_CALENDAR() - DAY( <date_or_timestamp_expr> )
DayOccurrence_Of_Month() - DAYOFMONTH( <date_or_timestamp_expr> )
QuarterNumber_Of_Year() - QUARTER( <date_or_timestamp_expr> )
WeekNumber_Of_Calendar() - WEEKOFYEAR( <date_or_timestamp_expr> )
```

Comment: only Quarter function is wroking. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is one way for the DAYOCCURANCE_OF_MONTH() hoping there's a more elegant approach someone can come up with.

[image]

`TRUNC(DATEDIFF(DAY,DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',CURRENT_DATE()),CURRENT_DATE())/7)`

Answer (score 0):

```
DayOccurrence_Of_Month() -> EXTRACT(DAY FROM <date>)
WeekNumber_Of_Calendar() -> DATE_PART(week, <date>)
MonthNumber_Of_Quarter() -> DATE_PART(month, <date>)
QuarterNumber_Of_Year() -> DATE_PART(quarter, <date>)
```